# Certbot certificate invalid - Certbot/ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ssl, ssl-certificate, certbot

I'm developing a Website on my own server via ReactJS.
I created a Certbot (Let's Encrypt) certificate for my domains (with and without www.).
All of my domains lead to the right External IP -> both domains working.
Now when I edit the package.json of my React such that HTTPS is true and give both paths of the fullchain.pem as well as privkey.pem, it tells me whenever I try to run `npm start` that the certificate is invalid even though I just created it 2 minutes before.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "set HTTPS=true&& set SSL_CRT_FILE=ssl\\fullchain.pem&& set SSL_KEY_FILE=ssl\\privkey.pem&& react-scripts start",
  // ...
}
```

this is my error when trying to start:
"The Certificate "path/fullchain.pem" is invalid.
error:03000096:digital envelope routines::operation not supported for this keytype"

Why is that?
Thanks already!